# Unable to get Last-Modified from PHP header in shell script

Tags: php, bash, shell

I am using a bash shell script to retrieve the Last-Modified value from several webpages (Thanks Lri!).  Here is the code that I am using:

```
#!/bin/bash

url=http://www.mywebsite.com
tempdir=~/Library/Caches/scripts
temp=$tempdir/mywebsite
mkdir -p $tempdir
modified=$(curl -sI "$url" | grep ^Last-Modified)
if [[ -f "$temp" && "$modified" != "$(cat $temp)" ]]; then
terminal-notifier -message 'Example changed'
fi
printf %s "$modified" > $temp
```

When I run the script on index.html, the output is: Last-Modified: Wed, 06 Nov 2013 00:20:49 GMT (which is correct).

When I run the script against on index.php, I get no nothing in the output.

Could someone please explain to me the code that I need to include in the .php page or in the shell script to correct the problem?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The web server can determine the Last-Modified date based on the timestamp of the .html file.

This doesn't work for PHP files, since PHP pages are usually dynamic. In these cases, it's up to the developer to determine what constitutes a logical modification, and send an appropriate header.

Here's an example that just sets the last modified time to the current date:

```
<?PHP
header( 'Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s' ) . ' GMT' );
?>
```

For a blog, you might instead want to set the Last-Modified date to be that of the most recently updated article displayed on the page. For a weather forecast, you could set it to the last time the source data was updated for the location you're currently looking at.

Comment: Let me add a couple of details here...  I am the webmaster of several sites, some of which have been the targets for hackers and phishers.  I want to run the script a few times daily (maybe 4 or so) to detect if any changes have been made to the website.  That way, if it shows a new modification date and I didn't make any changes, then I can take the appropriate action.  (Current date and time won't work here since it would always show that the site was changed.)  When I FTP into the sites, the Unix system updates the modification date and I would like to pull that date out via the script.

Comment: Looking at the Last-Modified date of the site is the wrong way of doing this. Use an IDS like Tripwire.